# Stack trace in release RSLs

Tags: flash, apache-flex, stack, trace, rsl

Since flash player 11.5 it is possible to get stack trace for uncaught errors, very handy for logging runtime errors in production and an immense help with debugging. But the problem I am facing atm is that the stack trace contains only the information from the application .swf (if it was compiled as -swf-version=18), but if the error was thrown in a piece of code that is in the RSLs, the stack trace for that is skipped.

Which means I end up with stack trace for the triggering event in the application (if lucky) and then generic framework stack trace that is not of much help.

Have tried hooking up uncaught event handlers on the rsls themselves on rslComplete, no change. Any ideas